# Finding the latest version for BIOS

Tags: bios

I want to update the BIOS of my PC, but I can't find the site to download the version. it is:

> BIOS Version/Date:   Award Software International, Inc, F2, 12/16/2009

And here is information about the motherboard in my computer:

> Manufacturer  Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd.

> Model  EP41T-UD3L (Socket 775)

I searched a lot but I couldn't find a site for update this version of BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-EP41T-UD3L-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios

Found by Google in 0.49 seconds plus a couple of clicks.

Comment: Thanks, but these are for the date 2009 or 2010. I'm looking for new versions.

Comment: There are no newer versions.